# Eclipse doesnt Automatically Check out all Affected Java files when Refactoring

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, clearcase

I am coding Java using Eclipse 3.5 with ClearCase.

I need to refactor a method in an interface to rename it causing knock-on changes to about 4-5 different classes. The problem is when I use the Refactor->Rename... menu action, eclipse only prompts me to check out the interface file that I am editing and not the other affected files.

In Preferences->Team->ClearCase Remote Client->Workspace my settings are as following:

```
When edited by an internal, interactive editor: Prompt to checkout
When edited by an internal, non-interactive editor: Automatically checkout
When saved by an internal editor: Automatically checkout
```

Does anyone know any setting to get eclipse to find & automatically prompt for checkout all the affected files for the change?

Comment: Good luck on your search. Clearcase plugins and Eclipse are not a happy marriage, simple things like renaming or deleting files often don't work. Whether the fault is on the plugin side or the Eclipse side who can say.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of CCRC/ClearCase you are using.
The [first ones  (2003) has many issues](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21194893), and the recent ones (7.1.2.x) should handle that more gracefully.
Note that [both the ClearCase plugin for Eclipse and CCRC support refactoring](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233091).

Don't forget though that there still are instances when a refactor won't complete fully, especially when:

- the parent directory of the file is already checked-out
- the files are hijacjed (or eclipsed if you are using a dynamic view)